# Java Concurrent Modification Exception after synchronizing

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list, synchronized

I have a LinkedList of objects im trying to iterate over(using an iterator), see if they have any collision, if so, remove it from the list. However, I am getting a concurrent modification exception. I put it in a synchronized block, and I also tried catching the error in a try catch block, neither seem to help at all, the code is here:

```
private void updateTP() {
    synchronized (toiletpaper) {
        Iterator<ToiletPaper> iter = toiletpaper.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ToiletPaper tp = iter.next();
            tp.update(1000, 700);
            if (toilet.overlaps(tp)) {
                System.out.println("tp splash!");
                toiletpaper.remove(tp);
                menu.removeLife();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on the problem would be appreciated, I looked through here and google, and all of them said either catch the exception or synchronize it, which neither seem to work so... please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid the exception, use [`iter.remove()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29) instead. This will remove the element via the iterator instance, rather than the current call, which searches and removes from the list separately - that is, a concurrent modification.

Comment: +1 -- and (at least in this case) it has nothing to do with `synchronized`. It's a poorly named exception; it's more like an "out-of-band modification".

Comment: It is all very well saying it is poorly named, but I've yet to see an alternative name that us unambiguously better.  (And the reason it confuses people is that "concurrent" has two distinct meanings ... "happening at the same time", and "involving multiple threads of control".)

Answer (score 2):

It is throwing an exception because you're modifying the collection directly with `toiletpaper.remove(tp);`.  You have to use `iter.remove()` to modify the collection while iterating over it.

Answer (score 2):

When you do the `toiletpaper.remove(tp)` you modify your linked list (you relink it) and therefore you get that error; your iterator is no longer valid.